# How to make a 2D sphere with decreasing radial gradient

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I'm using this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 

\begin{document}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{135}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{45}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{75}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=9,tdplot_main_coords]
    \shade[tdplot_screen_coords,ball color = gray!60] (0,0) circle (\rvec);
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}

    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \draw[-stealth,color=black] (O) -- (P) node[midway,above] {$r$};
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);
    \tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\phi$}

    \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{\thetavec}{90}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{\rvec}{-180}{180}{anchor=south west}{}
  \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

which creates:

[image]

How to apply decreasing radial gradient?

The intended result would be something like (with the axes, etc remaining visible):

[image]

Comment: Do you want the axes also to "fade away" or only the sphere?

Comment: Only the sphere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want only a radial fading, then the example just before section 23.4.2 may be the way to go.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade out,
inner color=transparent!0,
outer color=transparent!100]

\begin{document}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{135}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{45}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{75}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=9,tdplot_main_coords]
    \fill[tdplot_screen_coords,gray!40!black,%ball color = gray,
    path fading=fade out] (0,0) circle (\rvec);
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}

    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \draw[-stealth,color=black] (O) -- (P) node[midway,above] {$r$};
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);
    \tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\phi$}

    \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{\thetavec}{90}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{\rvec}{-180}{180}{anchor=south west}{}
  \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to slightly slightly modify the fuzzy circles from the `shadings` library. (I merely copied and slightly modified the fuzzy circle fading from the library to give you immediate access to the transparency levels at different distances. I am not claiming that my choice is particularly nice, but in the end you need to decide yourself what suits you best. The number 23 does not really represent a percentage, but if you play basketball you may understand why I picked it. ;-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareradialshading{tikz@lib@fade@circle@23}{\pgfpointorigin}{
  color(0pt)=(pgftransparent!0); color(20bp)=(pgftransparent!50);
  color(25bp)=(pgftransparent!92); color(50bp)=(pgftransparent!100)}
\pgfdeclarefading{circle with fuzzy edge 23 percent}{\pgfuseshading{tikz@lib@fade@circle@23}}
\makeatother
\tikzfading[name=fade out,
inner color=transparent!0,
outer color=transparent!100]

\begin{document}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{135}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{45}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{75}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=9,tdplot_main_coords]
    \shade[tdplot_screen_coords,ball color=gray!60,
    path fading={circle with fuzzy edge 23 percent}] (0,0) circle (\rvec);
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}

    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \draw[-stealth,color=black] (O) -- (P) node[midway,above] {$r$};
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (O) -- (Pxy);
    \draw[dashed, color=red] (P) -- (Pxy);
    \tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\phi$}

    \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{\thetavec}{90}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
    \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{\rvec}{-180}{180}{anchor=south west}{}
  \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

replace the \ shade line with

`\node[circle,shading=radial,outer color=gray!30,inner color=black!80, minimum width=14.5cm]{};